# What's wrong with my hill cipher code? (Java Android)

Tags: java, android, cryptography

I have some problems in implementing the hill cipher algorithm in Java Android. It runs well on certain condition but it comes lack on other condition.

Here is the running app.

**1. It runs OK for below condition**

[image: **Ok for below input**]

**2. It comes with unexpected result for below condition**

[image: the problem comes here]

I'm just figuring that the problem comes from the negative results. I used the determinant and multiplicative invers to find the matrix invers.

here is the code of my project.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.andri.hilltest;

import java.util.Arrays;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    EditText txtPlain, txtKey, txtCipher, txtDecrypt;
    Button btnEncrypt, btnCheck, btnDecrypt;
    String char_db = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789 ?!.,";
    //String char_db = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabc";
    int[] array_angka, array_angka2;
    int[] array_angka_cipher, array_angka_decrypted;



int[][] M_key = new int[2][2];
int[][] M_inverse = new int [2][2];
int i;
String key_input, ciphertext, plaintext;
int db_length = char_db.length();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    txtPlain = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPlain);
    txtKey = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtKey);
    txtCipher = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtCipher);
    txtDecrypt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtDecrypt);


    btnEncrypt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEncrypt);
    btnDecrypt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDecrypt);
    btnCheck = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCheck);

    btnEncrypt.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnCheck.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnDecrypt.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v == btnEncrypt){

        String plainTextInput = txtPlain.getText().toString();

        char[] array_huruf = plainTextInput.toCharArray();

        if(array_huruf.length%2!=0)
            array_angka = new int[array_huruf.length+1];
        else
            array_angka = new int[array_huruf.length];

        for (i=0 ; i < array_huruf.length ; i++){

            int posisi_huruf =  char_db.indexOf(array_huruf[i]);

            //Toast.makeText(this, "Tombol ditekan " +  posisi_huruf , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            array_angka[i] = posisi_huruf; //if I disable this line the code should run well
        }



        //jika panjang array ganjil letakkan spasi diakhir array
        if(array_huruf.length % 2 != 0 ){
            array_angka[array_huruf.length] = 62;
        }



        array_angka_cipher = new int[array_angka.length];

        array_angka_cipher = encrypt_hill(M_key, array_angka);

        ciphertext = to_char(array_angka_cipher);
        txtCipher.setText(Arrays.toString(array_angka) +"\n\n" + Arrays.toString(array_angka_cipher) + "\n\n" + to_char(array_angka_cipher) );


    }

    else if (v == btnCheck){
        key_input = txtKey.getText().toString(); 

        if (key_input.length() < 4)
            Toast.makeText(this, "panjang kunci harus 4 karakter!" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        else{
            check_kunci(key_input);
        }
    }

    else if(v == btnDecrypt){
        char[] array_cipher = ciphertext.toCharArray();
        array_angka2 = new int[array_cipher.length];

        for (i=0 ; i < array_cipher.length ; i++){

            int posisi_huruf =  char_db.indexOf(array_cipher[i]);
            array_angka2[i] = posisi_huruf; 
        }

        array_angka_decrypted = new int[array_cipher.length];
        array_angka_decrypted = decrypt_hill(M_inverse, array_angka2);

        plaintext = to_char(array_angka_decrypted);

        txtDecrypt.setText(Arrays.toString(array_angka2) + "\n\n" + Arrays.toString(array_angka_decrypted) + "\n\n" + plaintext);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void check_kunci(String kunci){

    Toast.makeText(this, kunci  , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    char[] array_kunci = kunci.toCharArray();

    int j = 0;

    while ( j < array_kunci.length){

        //masukkan masing-masing nilai ke matriks kunci
        for (int x=0; x < 2; x++){
            for (int y=0; y<2; y++){
                M_key[x][y] = char_db.indexOf(array_kunci[j]);
                j = j+1;
            }
        }
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, "hello " + M_key[0][0] + " " + M_key[0][1] + " " + M_key[1][0] + " " + M_key[1][1]   , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    int det = determinant(M_key);
    Toast.makeText(this, " determinant = " + det   , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (det == 0){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Kunci invalid karena determinant = 0"   , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (det%67==0){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Kunci invalid karena determinan memiliki persamaan faktor dgn 67"   , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Kunci Valid, multiplication inverse " + mi(det)   , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        M_inverse = getInverse(M_key, mi(det));
        Toast.makeText(this, "Inverse berhasil" + M_inverse[0][0] + " " + M_inverse[0][1] + " " + M_inverse[1][0] + " " + M_inverse[1][1]  , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        String tampil_banding = M_key[0][0] + " " + M_key[0][1] + " " + M_key[1][0] + " " + M_key[1][1] +"\n\n" + M_inverse[0][0] + " " + M_inverse[0][1] + " " + M_inverse[1][0] + " " + M_inverse[1][1];

        txtCipher.setText(tampil_banding);
    }


}

public int[] encrypt_hill(int[][] key, int[] p){
    int str_length;
    str_length = txtPlain.length();

    if(str_length%2!=0)
        str_length = str_length+1;

    int[] c = new int[str_length];
    int i = 0;
    int zz = 0;

    for (int b=0; b< str_length/2 ; b++){
        for(int j=0; j<2; j++){
            for(int x=0; x<2 ; x++){
                c[i] += key[j][x]*p[x+zz];
            }
            i++;
        }
        zz += 2;
    }
    return c;
}

private String to_char(int[] num_cipher){
    int[] mod_result = new int[num_cipher.length];

    char[] parse_cipher = new char[num_cipher.length];

    for(int i=0;i<num_cipher.length;i++){
        mod_result[i] = Math.abs(num_cipher[i]%67);
        parse_cipher[i] = char_db.charAt(mod_result[i]);
    }

    String cipher_result = new String(parse_cipher);

    return cipher_result;
}

public int determinant(int[][] A){

    int res;

    res = A[0][0]*A[1][1] - A[1][0]*A[0][1];

    return res;
}



public int[][] getInverse(int key[][], int mi){
    int[][] key_inv = new int[2][2];

    key_inv[0][0] = ((key[1][1]*mi)%67);
    key_inv[0][1] = (((-1*key[0][1])*mi)%67);
    key_inv[1][0] = (((-1*key[1][0])*mi)%67);
    key_inv[1][1] = ((key[0][0]*mi)%67);

    return key_inv;

}

public int mi(int d)
{
    int q,r1,r2,r,t1,t2,t;
    r1=67;
    r2=d;
    t1=0;
    t2=1;

    while(r1!=1&&r2!=0)
    {
        q=r1/r2;
        r=r1%r2;
        t=t1-(t2*q);
        r1=r2;
        r2=r;
        t1=t2;
        t2=t;
    }

    return (t1+t2);
}

public int[] decrypt_hill(int[][] key_invers, int[] p){
    int str_length;
    str_length = txtPlain.length();

    if(str_length%2!=0)
        str_length = str_length+1;

    int[] c = new int[str_length];
    int i = 0;
    int zz = 0;

    for (int b=0; b< str_length/2 ; b++){
        for(int j=0; j<2; j++){
            for(int x=0; x<2 ; x++){
                c[i] += key_invers[j][x]*p[x+zz];
            }
            i++;
        }
        zz += 2;
    }
    return c;
}
```

For now I'm suspecting that the problem comes from the determinant, mi (multiplicative inverse) and getInverse function. I really hope someone out there could help me to find out what's wrong with my code or my algorithm.

After all I really appreciate your attentions and intentions to help me. Thank you very much guys. I'm sorry if my code a little bit messy, because I'm still a beginner in this matters.

Answer (score 0):

from wikipage http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_cipher

Not all matrices have an inverse (see invertible matrix). The matrix will have an inverse if and only if its determinant is not zero, and does not have any common factors with the modular base. Thus, if we work modulo 26 as above, the determinant must be nonzero, and must not be divisible by 2 or 13. If the determinant is 0, or has common factors with the modular base, then the matrix cannot be used in the Hill cipher, and another matrix must be chosen (otherwise it will not be possible to decrypt). Fortunately, matrices which satisfy the conditions to be used in the Hill cipher are fairly common.

"abay" is not a valid key of hill cipher.

SORRY for not reading you code carefully.

try change

```
mod_result[i] = Math.abs(num_cipher[i]%67);
```

to

```
mod_result[i] = (((num_cipher[i]%67) + 67)%67);
```

or

```
mod_result[i] = num_cipher[i]%67;
if(mod_result[i] <0){
    mod_result[i] += 67;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, mate. But in this condition, I'm not working on modulo 26, I am using 67 characters, as we know that it is a prime number. Does it hold the same condition? Or could u tell me it must not be divisible by what number to be a valid key...